# Is there a way how to obtain credentials stored in current session only?

Tags: .net, windows, winapi

### What I want to achieve (background)

Obtain SID of a user which is used to connect to the computer in the Windows network without the domain.

Just simple Windows sharing is used. When user browser computer share in the network, he is eventualy prompted for the credentials which are stored in the credentials cache.

There are three cases (as I found):

1. The logged user on the local computer matches (with name and
   password) the user on the computer in the network. Then no prompt is
   shown and user is logged automatically on the network computer.
2. The logged user on the lcal computer does not match any existing
   user on the network computer. User is prompted with the dialog to
   enter username and password with optional possibility to remember
   entered credentials - this could lead to:

   2.1. User does tick to remember entered credentials - then they are
     stored in the credentials cache and available there even when the
     user log off and log in again.

   2.2. User does not tick to remember
     entered credentials - then they are stored in some session
     credentials cache and used until the user log off.

### What I know (did)

- How to translate user name to it's SID - can be done using API method ([`LookupAccountName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159(v=vs.85).aspx), even for the user stored on the network computer). *That actually helps me to solve the case 1. because I just simply translate current user name to the SID on remote computer.*
- How to read credentials cache and obtain a username for respective computer when it is stored there - can be done using combination of the methods [`CredGetTargetInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374798(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`CredReadDomainCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374805(v=vs.85).aspx) *which will help me to solve the case 2.1.*

### What is my question (the problem)

And what I do not know - if there is a way how to solve the case 2.2 - because I cannot find the way how to obtain credentials which are stored in the current session only. That means when user is promted from them but does not tick the store / remember checkbox. They cannot be found in the credentials cache but yet they are used when user access the remote computer again during that login session.

**Last note**: the project is actually written in c# (.NET2.0) but I am using pinvoke to call these mentioned methods. If there is a framework way to achieve what I want to do, then excelent but Windows API is ok too.